# Can Ubuntu/Gnome prompt me to save unsaved documents during logout/restart/shutdown?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, libreoffice

Let's say I have unsaved documents in LibreOffice or in text editors. If I logout/restart/shutdown, Ubuntu doesn't ask me to save files. It seems like Ubuntu doesn't close programs gracefully.

Is there a way to get prompted to save unsaved documents during session close? (Like Windows does.)

Note: I've found below related issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/276134

Ubuntu 20.04
Gnome 3.36.8

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Gnome is doing their part.
https://discourse.gnome.org/t/can-ubuntu-prompt-me-to-save-unsaved-documents-during-logout-restart-shutdown/6393

So, applications need to add this feature.